# Not able to access my App delegate properties & methods in another class in ios 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a avery strange issue.Let me first post the code to you

**In my appdelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@class MasterViewController;
@class DetailViewController1;


@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {


   NSTimer *tempTimer;

}


@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *tempTimer;


-(void)test;


@end


In my app delegate .m

@synthesize tempTimer
```

**In my SecondViewController.h**

```
@class TestAppDelegate;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{


    TestAppDelegate *appDel;
    NSTimer *aTimer;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *aTimer;


@end
```

**In my SecondViewController.m**

```
@synthesize   aTimer, appDel;
```

In `viewDidload` method

```
appDel =(TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.aTimer = appDel.tempTimer;
```

Now I get following error

*Property "tempTimer" not found on object of type "TestAppDelegate *"*

Comment: Is "testTimer" a typo in the error? It seems to be "tempTimer".

Comment: sorry its my mistake, look I have edited the question.Its tempTimer everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, you have forward declared TestAppDelegate in SecondViewController and hence cannt access the properties. And i think the reason you did this is to avoid circular dependency among these classes. You have two options:

- **Import TestAppDelegate.h in SecondViewController.m.** OR
- Remove the circular dependency and import TestAppDelegate in SecondViewController.h instead of @class TestAppDelegate;

Comment: @UdayKumar thanks anyway!I was thinking it might be because of cyclic dependency but I was not sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add #import "appdelegate.h" to the top of SecondViewController.m You do not need to add it to the top of the header file as doing that will cause all classes that use SecondViewController to also import appdelegate.h but by doing that in the m file it is only imported for the methods pertaining to SecondViewController.m